# likelihood of data given parameter or likelihood of parameter given data?

Tags: terminology, regression, maximum-likelihood

What is more correct? Likelihood of data given parameter or likelihood of parameter given data? In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function for instance, we see both

- likelihood of $\hat{\theta}$
- but also maximizing the likelihood of the specific observation $x_{j}$

what is best?

Consider Modern Mathematical Statistics with Application by Devore, Berk, and Carlton, Chapter 7 Point Estimation, subsection Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

The authors claim:

> It is called the maximum likelihood estimate because for fixed
> x1, ..., x10, it is the parameter value that maximizes the
> likelihood (joint pmf) of the observed sample.

Therefore, likelihood is always of the observed sample? In other words, likelihood is always likelihood of data?

[image]

Comment: what does “best” mean here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the definition of a likelihood function is: Given a random variable $X$ with a value of $x$, we want to know the probability that some unknown parameter has a true value of $\theta$. Then, we call the likelihood function:
$$\mathcal{L}(\theta | x)$$ Which is defined differently for discrete and continuous random variables. Specifically, your question asks which is more correct, the likelihood of $\theta$ (yes) or maximizing the likelihood of the specific observation $x$ (not really).

The likelihood function is defined to be the likehood of $\theta$ given that $X = x$. So, calling it the likelihood of $\theta$ is clearly correct. However, we have an equivalent function that can tell us the probability of getting $x$ given a parameter $\theta$, which we call the p.d.f. of $x$. However, $\mathcal{L}(\theta | x)$ does not tell us that, $f(x | \theta)$ tells us the likelihood of our event given the parameter. It's the same function, but in one version we fix $x$, the likelihood function, and the other version we fix $\theta$, which is a probability density function.

If you would like a reputable source, you may read *Modern Mathematical Statistics with Application* by *Devore*, *Berk*, and *Carlton*, Chapter 7 Point Estimation, subsection Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

Edit: I cannot find your quote, and page 353 is not what I cite but, directly from the book on page 547 (the page number not pdf number):

> As before, denote the joint pmf or pdf of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ by
> $f (x_1,x_n; \theta)$. In the case of a random sample, it will be a product $f(x1; \theta),\ldots, f(x_n; \theta)$. As in the
> development of maximum likelihood estimates, when $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n; \theta )$is regarded as a function of $\theta$, it is called the likelihood function and is sometimes denoted $L(\theta)$.

Based on your interpretation of the quote: sure. The maximum likelihood estimate, given a fixed sample $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, can be seen as the value of $\theta$ that maximizes $\mathcal{L}(\theta | x)$. But what you have written in your question at the top:

> likelihood of $\theta$ or maximizing the likelihood of the specific observation $x_j$

Refers to two different scenarios. When we look at a likelihood function in general, it tells us the likelihood of $\theta$ given our sample $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. If we want to *maximize* our likelihood function, then yes it tells us the value of $\theta$ that maximizes the likelihood that we will get our sample $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ compared to any other value of $\theta$.

Final edit
:
Yes. These are two different concepts:

A maximum likelihood esitmate is the value of $\theta$ that maximizes the likelihood that we can obtain our sample $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. This is found by $\max_\theta (\mathcal{L}(\theta | x))$, but to be clear it is not the only result that we can find from the likelihood function.

A likelihood function gives us the likelihood of a certain value of $\theta$ given that we have already observed the sample $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

So in your original question you ask which is better: If you have a maximum likelihood estimate, then maximizing the likelihood of the specific observation $x_j$ is best.

If you are simply referring to what a likelihood function does, then the likelihood of $\theta$ works best.

Comment: Looking at the book above, page 353, I read:

It is called the maximum likelihood estimate because for fixed x1, . . ., x10, it is the parameter value that maximizes the likelihood (joint pmf) of the observed sample.

note that in the excerpt above, the likelihood is of data, not of parameter

Comment: in the book that you referred to, the authors refer to likelihood of data, not likelihood of parameter. However, the likelihood function is a function of the parameters, right?  I'm thinking about terminology. Is it correct to talk about the likelihood of a parameter?

Comment: I updated for you, not sure where your quote is from since page 353 is a page of exercises from a  different chapter but I used a quote and talked about your interpretation of your quote. I hope that helps. Let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: dear Robert, I've copied/pasted the material from page 353 that I was referring to. Please, may you check it out? It is second edition

Comment: @DanielS. I put in the last edit to clarifty any confusion hopefully. Let me know if you are still confused but please be specific.

Comment: my feeling is that the most precise terminology is to refer to likelihood of data, and to the likelihood function evaluated at a given value set for parameter theta -- the latter may be referred to as likelihood of parameter, as a shortcut to "likelihood function evaluated for a given parameter"

Comment: The most precise terminology is “Maximum likelihood estimate” and “value of the likelihood function for $\theta$ given $X$”